# Как скрыть часть данных на сайте?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript, mysql

Всем привет! Нужно реализовать две похожие задачи - Как скрыть часть данных на сайте от посетителя:

- а) до регистрации
- б) до оплаты доступа к этим данным

Как лучше реализовать такую логику? И какими средствами? Как это сделать технически?

Comment: Технически - это банальная задача на разграничение прав доступа. Вполне реализуется средствами php и mysql, можно украсить средствами клиентских наворотов. В остальном - посмотрите чем в любых рекомендациях к реализации регистраций пользователей зарегистрированный пользователь отличается от анонимного. Так же решите и задачу с оплатой.

Answer (score 1):

на PHP отлавливать статус пользователя в программе.
Если не авторезирован то выведем как есть.
Если авторезирован то рисуем расширенный контент.
Если оплатил то дорисовываем данные.